# textobj-user: must the patterns be different?

Tags: cursor-motions, custom-text-object, plugin-textobj-user

I'm trying to make a text-object that is a paragraph surrounded by lines containing `%`. To test something simpler, I tried:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('pc', {
\   'code': {
\     'pattern': ['%<', '%'],
\     'scan': 'nearest',
\     'region-type': 'V',
\     'select-i': 'ir',
\   },
\ })
```

which works, but if I use `%` instead of `%<`, it doesn't. Must the patterns be different? Why?

Comment: Because there is no way to know when you are *inside* the pattern, or *between* two other `%`-delimited regions? You could use something like this, perhaps: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-syntax

Comment: @VanLaser, yes, but maybe it could assume that one is inside, behave like the paragraph object.

Comment: It could, but AFAIK it doesn't. I think if it finds the starting pattern, it simply doesn't 'move' the selection to the end pattern, if it's the same one.

Comment: I *think* that it first searches before the cursor for the start pattern, then searches the end pattern, and it cancels selection if the end pattern is not *after* the original cursor position. But I don't have the patience to look into the code, feel free to do so :)

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a know issue (see issues [#2](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/issues/2) and [#15](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/issues/15) in the plugin bug tracker).

The author of the plugin suggested a workaround of the following form:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('handyobjects', {
\   'underscores_a': {
\     'select': 'ar',
\     '*pattern*': '%[^%]*%'
\   },
\   'underscores_i': {
\     'select': 'ir',
\     '*pattern*': '%\zs[^%]\+\ze%'
\   },
\ })
```

The idea is not to use a beginning and a ending pattern but just one regex to match the region:

- For the `ar` motion the regex `%[^%]*%` defines a region starting with a `%` followed by anything which is not `%` repeated zero or more times (i.e. `[^$]*`) followed by another `%`.
- For the `ir` motion the regex is more or less the same but the match excludes the delimitating `%` characters thanks to `\zs` and `\ze`.

So it is possible to use the same pattern for begin and end but you need to use only one regex.

**Important note** This is a workaround and it has a major drawback: I wasn't able to use it to match a region on several lines (which can be a problem in some cases).

**Edit** In some cases it is possible to create text objects which matches the same pattern on different lines. Here is what the author [suggested](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/issues/48) to match two `_` on different lines:

```
call textobj#user#plugin('handyobjects', {
\   'underscores_a': {
\     'select': 'au',
\     'pattern': '_\_[^_]*_'
\   },
\   'underscores_i': {
\     'select': 'iu',
\     'pattern': '_\zs\_[^_]\+\ze_'
\   },
\ })
```

**Note** That after a really quick test I wasn't able to make it work with `%` characters but I guess it what because of some escaping problem or something like this. I think that with some work on the regex it is possible to do it.